# C# LINQ Queries - Get File Extension Type using IEnumerable<string>

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, file-extension

I currently have a method that recursively enumerates all the files on my desktop and returns them as an `IEnumerable<string>`. What I am trying to now do is create a method that takes that `IEnumerable<string>` as the parameter and uses LINQ to group/order them by their file type. I am having trouble getting the file types. After experimenting, I have gotten this:

```
foreach(string file in files){
                FileInfo f = new FileInfo(file);
                Console.WriteLine(f.Extension);
                
}
```

I am able to get the extensions of all files, but cannot figure out how to get that information using a LINQ query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the GroupBy method:

```
var files = new[] { "c://file1.txt", "c://file2.png", "c://file3.txt" };
var groups = files.Select(f => new FileInfo(f)).GroupBy(file => file.Extension, file => file, 
    (key, g) => new
{
    Extension = key, Files = g.OrderBy(f => f.Name).ToList()
});
foreach (var fileGroup in groups)
{
    var ext = fileGroup.Extension;
    var innerFiles = fileGroup.Files;
    Console.WriteLine($@"Files with extension {ext}: {innerFiles.Count} files");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To order :

```
List<string> listOrdered = files.OrderBy(x=>Path.GetExtension(x)).ToList()
```

To Group :

```
List<List<string>> listGroupped = files.GroupBy(x => Path.GetExtension(x))
            .Select(grp => grp.ToList())
            .ToList();
```

So you have a `List` of `List<string>`, in which you have all the files of the same extnsion.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `List<List<string>>` I would suggest using a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`.

```cs
Dictionary<string, List<string>> filesByExtension =
    files
        .GroupBy(file => Path.GetExtension(file))
        .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.ToList());

// Then later you can get all files with a specific extension.
List<string> executableFiles = filesByExtension[".exe"];

// If you want to display them, ordered by file extension.
foreach (string fileExtension in filesByExtensions.Keys.OrderBy(key => key))
{
    List<string> files = filesByExtensions[fileExtension];
}
```

Comment: Well, for a "new user" list is quite enough (then List and Dictionary have both their advantages). About your answer all is ok, but I don't understand people advising very complicated solutions. I went through that, and having "better" answers sometimes make more confuse (maybe too much opinion oriented for SO?)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a lookup which is similar to a dictionary but the value is an enumerable, so you never get an exception if you ask for an item that is not contained(in this case a file-extension):

Get the desktop files:

```
var desktopFiles = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory))
    .EnumerateFiles()
    .Concat(new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDesktopDirectory)).EnumerateFiles());
```

Here comes the important code, a one-liner:

```
var extensionLookup = desktopFiles.ToLookup(file => file.Extension, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Now use it to get some files into lists. But note that you could also append `Count()` to just count them, or use all other LINQ methods:

```
var exeFiles = extensionLookup[".exe"].ToList(); // empty on my desktop
var txtFiles = extensionLookup[".txt"].ToList();
var inkFiles = extensionLookup[".ink"].ToList();
```

You can also loop all available files by their type:

```
foreach(var x in extensionLookup)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Extension: {x.Key} File-Count: {x.Count()}");
    Console.WriteLine($"All Files: {string.Join(Environment.NewLine, x.Select(f => f.Name))}");
}
```